# Сбой физики в phaser.js

Tags: разработка-игр, phaser-framework

Делаю небольшую пошаговую (по 25 секунд на ход) сетевую игру на Phaser.js (физика P2), по принципу аэрохоккея.

Суть работы такова. Когда ходит один игрок (запускает свою фишку по принципу angry birds, то есть оттягивает и указывает направление), то на сервер передается ID спрайта, velocity.x и velocity.y. А с сервера соответственно уходят эти данные второму игроку и фишке с таким же ID присваиваются данные приложенного ускорения. Все в принципе работает как надо. У обоих игроков все фишки на поле выстраиваются одинаково. Но, время от времени (хотя бы 1 раз за игру) происходит сбой и фишки одного игрока перемещаются по полю отлично от фишек другого.

У всех спрайтов задано body.setCircle(radius). Граница поля задана вручную (rectangle по белой линии).

Может кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой и подскажет как ее решить. Может помимо скорости нужно еще какие параметры передавать на сервер?

[image: скрин]

Comment: @Kromster, игра пошаговая, по 25 секунд на ход

Comment: Вы наверное правы, по всей видимости какое-то "микро" движение остается, и в двух игроков оно разное. Во всяком случае угловая скорость есть точно. Тогда может подскажите как полностью остановить спрайт в этом движке при передаче хода?

Comment: Да, я так сейчас и сделал, просто думал может есть что-то "из коробки" для этого. Но появилась вот новая проблема. Если перейти на другую вкладку, то анимация останавливается, и при возврате продолжается. Если за время пока была закрыта вкладка противник сделал ход, то при возврате на вкладку игры, ход совершается когда анимация предыдущего хода еще не закончена и отсюда новый рассинхрон. Надо как-то победить остановку анимации при неактивной вкладке, так как игра на времени завязана

Comment: хорошо )) Как конвертировать ваш комментарий в ответ, чтоб я принял? А то уже давненько тут не был, все поменялось

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @Kromster за подсказку об "остаточном движении". Именно в этом и крылась проблема.

> А как вы синхронизируете время? Игроки ходят строго по очереди (как в шахматах) или одновременно? – Kromster
>
> Добавьте вывод отладочной информации в лог, сравните логи игроков, найдите отличие, выясните откуда оно взялось, исправьте. – Kromster
>
> А во время хода игрока все фишки статичны или еще есть какое-то остаточное движение? – Kromster
>
> Вы наверное правы, по всей видимости какое-то "микро" движение остается, и в двух игроков оно разное. Во всяком случае угловая скорость есть точно. Тогда может подскажите как полностью остановить спрайт в этом движке при передаче хода? – DemoS
>
> С движком не знаком, но вы скорее всего можете в конце хода обнулить все скорости и сверить все положения. – Kromster 3 часа назад

Помог следующий код:

```js
this._players.setAll('body.velocity.x', 0);
this._players.setAll('body.velocity.y', 0);
this._ball.body.velocity.x = 0;
this._ball.body.velocity.y = 0;
this._ball.body.angularVelocity = 0;
```